# apache pop3 bufferedreader lines end with = (equals)

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3

I try to receive some messages from a POP3 mail server using the apache POP3 mail client.

I use a BufferedReader to get messages from my POP3 mail server (*retreiveMessage(id)*). I have some mails with long lines and I read them with a loop like below. My lines are truncated into several lines ending with the equal sign (=), each line with 76 chars plus the =.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.pop3.POP3Client;
import org.apache.commons.net.pop3.POP3MessageInfo;

...


        POP3Client pop = new POP3Client();
        pop.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
        pop.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
        pop.connect(MAIL_SEREVR, PORT);
        String username = USERNAME;
        String password = PASSWORD;
        isVerified = pop.login(username, password);
        POP3MessageInfo[] messages = pop.listMessages();
        for (POP3MessageInfo msginfo : messages) {
            Date timestamp = new Date();
            BufferedReader reader = (BufferedReader) pop
                    .retrieveMessage(msginfo.number);

            if (reader == null) {
                System.err.println("Could not retrieve message header.");
                pop.disconnect();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            try {
                printMessageInfo(reader, msginfo.number, timestamp);                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pop.deleteMessage(msginfo.number);
        }
        pop.logout();
        pop.disconnect();
```

So, I print the messages and since a word is too long, it is truncated like this:

```
 this is a short line, it is OK
 andThisIsALongLineWithMoreThan76CharactersButThisIsEmpiricalIJustSeeThatThe=
 LineIsTruncatedAtThe76thCHAR
```

is this a normal behavior? can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: You are receiving something in Base-64 encoding. I've never seen JavaMail behave like that. Are you really using it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't **sound** like you're using JavaMail.  It you aren't, use it, it will make life easier for you.  If you are, explain in more detail what you're doing.

Comment: Re-edit the question to add example and imports (apache mail client)

Comment: Simple answer - yes, this is completely normal.  You're looking at MIME quoted-printable encoded data.  Why are you using this API instead of JavaMail, which is much easier?